# ChartJs How to display horizontal and vertical lines through the datasets points with their values on axes?

Tags: chart.js

I found how to display values of points near them by using plugin, but couldn't find how to display grid lines through the datasets points with their values on axes. Could you help please?

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure this answer your question but have you checked chartjs popular extension like:

Plugin:
https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels

Tests
https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/samples/charts/line.html